# How to allow user to use loadConnectedPlayers

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to get all connected players to game. I can get players that are in google+ circles but I want the player to get all users. I can't find what permission do I need to do this.

I am using this code to get players, but it always returns 0.

```
PendingResult<LoadPlayersResult> players = Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers(mGoogleApiClient, false);

players.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPlayersResult result) 
    {
        PlayerBuffer buf = result.getPlayers(); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "players"+buf.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you done this issue yet? If yes, give us your solution, thanks !

Comment: Have you checked the status code of your result? Maybe this gives a hint on what is going wrong: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.LoadPlayersResult

Comment: Status code is STATUS_OK always. I think the reason is it's required permission "who can see your game activity"?. Can we add default full permissions when user sign in first time?

Answer (score 1):

this had been [pre-announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) and then [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html) a while ago already and method `.loadConnectedPlayers()` had been deprecated... which merely boils down to, that Google+ had been separated from Play Games and the functionality you are looking for is not available anymore.

in order to get a list of connected players, you would have to use your own API now. Just seen the question is old and had been posted before the announce - nevertheless this appears to be the current status.